# k6.io read binary file with TextDecoder file due to issue with util package

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, k6

I'm using k6.io tests and would like to import TextDecoder (from util package)

In my script, I would like to read the binary file:

```
import { sleep, check } from 'k6';
import { Options } from 'k6/options';
import http from 'k6/http';
/* @ts-ignore */
import { TextDecoder } from 'util';


export const options:Options = {
  vus: 1,
  iterations: 1,
};

const file = open('uuids.txt', 'b');


export function setup() {

  console.log("File is " + file);

  let enc = new TextDecoder("utf-8")

  console.log("Decode: " + enc.decode(file));


}

export default () => {

  .....post HTTP Request
  
}
```

My package.json with 'util' (npm install util --save-dev):

```
{
  "name": "typescript",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "ssh://git@github.com/k6io/example-typescript.git",
  "author": "Simon Aronsson <simme@k6.io>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.13.16",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.13.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "7.13.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.13.15",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.13.0",
    "@types/k6": "~0.41.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.4.5",
    "@types/webpack": "5.28.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.2.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-alpha.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^9.0.1",
    "typescript": "4.2.4",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "webpack": "5.61.0",
    "webpack-cli": "4.6.0",
    "webpack-glob-entries": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack"
  },
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false
  }
}
```

However, when I run my script: k6 run  I got, seems util package is not resolved. Could you please help me understand what is the reason?

```
k6 run dist\post-201-create-node-test.js

          /\      |‾‾| /‾‾/   /‾‾/
     /\  /  \     |  |/  /   /  /
    /  \/    \    |     (   /   ‾‾\
   /          \   |  |\  \ |  (‾)  |
  / __________ \  |__| \__\ \_____/ .io

ERRO[0000] ReferenceError: process is not defined
        at 539 (webpack://typescript/./node_modules/util/util.js:109:0(78))
        at __webpack_require__ (webpack://typescript/webpack/bootstrap:19:0(26))
        at webpack://typescript/external%20commonjs%20%22https://jslib.k6.io/k6-utils/1.4.0/index.js%22:1:34(47)
        at file:///C:/Dev//dist/post-201-create-node-test.js:2323:3(71)
        at file:///C:/Dev/dist/post-201-create-node-test.js:2328:12(3)  hint="script exception"
```

-----------------  RESOLVED ----------------

I resolved my problem by using my test data via SharedArray:

```
const data = new SharedArray('some data name', function () {
  return JSON.parse(open('./data.json')).uuids;
});
```

Comment: k6 cannot start external processes (which `util.js` seems to do). k6 is not a full JavaScript runtime (nor a browser) and is not able to run all npm packages. There's an open issue though to add `TextDecoder` to k6: https://github.com/grafana/k6/issues/2440

Comment: @knittl thank you for letting me know about that blocker. Seems it is time to get rid of k6, is not applicable for comprehensive testing with test data handling at all

Comment: What do you need `TextDecoder` for? k6 can natively read utf8-encoded text files just fine. Did you go through the k6 documentation? It has plenty of examples of how to import/include test data from files: https://k6.io/docs/examples/data-parameterization/, https://k6.io/docs/javascript-api/init-context/open/ – `open` already returns the file's decoded content (»Opens a file, reading all its contents into memory for use in the script.«)

Comment: @knitt I try to use npm modules as documented her:
https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/modules/

But I cannot e.g. use importJWK from npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/jose because it rely on TextEncoder. I would use it to authenticate so I could use a Bearer-token for my api-tests, but to no avail. Also the native package https://github.com/szkiba/xk6-jose seems broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do exactly? You don't need a `TextDecoder` object to get a file's content. [`open`](https://k6.io/docs/javascript-api/init-context/open/) can already read a file's content as string (assuming the file contains ASCII or UTF-8 encoded text). `uuids.txt` sounds like a file that would only contain UUIDs, which are usually encoded as hex digits separated by hyphens, so they can be purely represented with the ASCII charset.

```
const uuids = open('uuids.txt'); // uuids contains the content of the text file

export default function() {
  console.log(`First line of file: ${uuids.split('\n')[0]}`);  
}
```

Comment: Hello, I had binary file for test data, but after re-reading the documentation one more time I had to re-write tests to exclude binary data. So now it works perfectly with const data = new SharedArray('some data name', function () {
  return JSON.parse(open('./data.json')).uuids;
});
Thanks a lot for the help